# JSON Error when posting JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, post

I keep getting an error when trying to send JSON data to a site. But when I check the site, I see that all the data in json was sent and is correct.

The error I get is:

```
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

The code I have is:

```
let json = [
            "name": "john",
            "last name": "smith"
        ]

        do{

            let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(json, options: .PrettyPrinted)


            let url = NSURL(string: website)

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

            request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.HTTPBody = jsonData

            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data, response, error in

                if error != nil{
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                    return
                }

                do {
                    let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]

                    print("Result: \(result)")

                } catch {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }

            task.resume()

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

When I allow for fragments:

```
try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
```

I get another error:

```
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
```

I changed:

```
try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
```

to

```
try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
```

and I no longer get an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error happens when you print your result after the data is successfully sent to server.

`NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` requires the JSON to start with an object (`{}`) or an array (`[]`).

Try adding the `.AllowFragments` option like this:

```
let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
```

If it doesn't work, the data coming back from the server is invalid JSON. You should try printing the `response`'s `statusCode` and see if there is a problem.

If you control the server, you should look at what is sent back.

Comment: In my experience, this problem happens when the response from the server  is not a JSON object or array. Just try to wrap the response in an array.

Comment: It has to be done on the server. I don't know how the data is generated (PHP, .NET, JS, ...) but you need to add `[]` or `{}` around it.

Comment: I don't have access to the server. I have been using https://requestb.in to check if the data has been sent and sent correctly.

Comment: I understand, the JSON you send is fine. It is the JSON sent back from server in the response that is not formatted correctly. If you don't have access to the server, there is not much you can do unfortunately...