# iOS Swift:"JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."

Tags: json, swift

When I converting Json string to dictionary in swift I got the Issue:**Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}**

I don't know to fix the issue please give idea for fix the issue.Here I gave my code what i am tried..

The method for converting Json string to dictionary is,

```
func convertToDictionary(from text: String) throws -> [String: String] {
    guard let data = text.data(using: .utf8) else { return [:] }
    let anyResult: Any = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    return anyResult as? [String: String] ?? [:]
}
```

The Json String is: `"[{\"propertyId\":\"1\",\"inspectionTemplateId\":1118,\"value\":[{\"widgetControllerId\":141,\"value\":\"Flood Summary Name\"},{\"widgetControllerId\":142,\"value\":\"Did the property flood?\"},{\"widgetControllerId\":143,\"value\":\"no\"}]}]"`

And the Usage of method was:

```
let jsonString = NSString(data: responseObject as! Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
        print(jsonString)
        do {
            let dictionary:NSDictionary = try self.convertToDictionary(from: jsonString as String) as NSDictionary
            print(dictionary)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.  Try running your test through a JSON validator first.

Comment: is this valid json

Comment: try using `try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.allowFragments])`

Comment: Your JSON is an Array at top level by the way, an array of dictionary, but once you removed "\" before the `"`, it seems valid so you shouldn't get that error, you should get another one: returning empty: `[:]`.

Comment: That Json from server@Anbu.karthik

Comment: Why do you convert `Data` to `(NS)String` and then back to `Data`? Print the data (`print(data as NSData)`) and post the first bytes. And don't use `NSString` and `NSDictionary` in Swift.

Comment: @Larme your solution helped me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452385/json-text-did-not-start-with-array-or-object-and-option-to-allow-fragments-not-s)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON Error when posting JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059948/json-error-when-posting-json)

Comment: See my answer , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33951401/json-text-did-not-start-with-array-or-object-and-option-to-allow-fragments-not-s/33951557

Answer (score 25):

Read the error gentleman. Error is 'allow fragments not set'.
Just Just just set .allowFragments.
That's it. (Make sure response is not malformatted)

```
JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)
```

Comment: Useful :) However, are there any global solution to check the data in JSON? Because now I have: Error serializing json Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0."

Comment: @Oleksandr I assume its bc the plist is wrapped inside xml

Comment: Sorry, but where exactly is this setting found?

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
let str = "[{\"propertyId\":\"1\",\"inspectionTemplateId\":1118,\"value\":[{\"widgetControllerId\":141,\"value\":\"Flood Summary Name\"},{\"widgetControllerId\":142,\"value\":\"Did the property flood?\"},{\"widgetControllerId\":143,\"value\":\"no\"}]}]".utf8
let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(str), options: [])
print(json)
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of issue can also occur if you have a misconfigured server or your server is unreachable. If you receive this type of error from JSON deserialization you may try converting the data to a string and print it out. It may reveal an error like "502 Bad Gateway"