# iOS: Unable to convert Json String to Array in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In my project I want to convert Json String from server to Array but Unable to convert, But when I hard code(Directly gave the particular json string) the json string means that will be convert. Please help me to find the issue..

Here I gave the code what i am tried.

```
var params = NSMutableDictionary()
    params = [
        "inspectionLogId": inspectionLogIdStr
    ]
    let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
    manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
    manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer()
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = NSSet(array: ["text/plain", "text/html", "application/json"]) as Set<NSObject> as Set<NSObject>! as! Set<String>?
    manager.requestSerializer.setValue("", forHTTPHeaderField: "apptoken")
    manager.requestSerializer.setValue(strAppToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "token")
    let urlString:NSString = NSString(format: "%@%@", ApiConstantFile().baseUrlProperty,ApiConstantFile().getTemplateDataUrl)
    print(urlString)
    manager.get(urlString as String, parameters: params, progress: nil, success: {
        (operation, responseObject) in
        self.stopAnimation()

        let jsonstring = String(data: responseObject! as! Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print("jsonstring is:, \(jsonstring!)")

        let data = jsonstring!.data(using: .utf8)!
        print(data)
        do {
            if (try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? [Dictionary<String,Any>]) != nil {
                let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as! [Dictionary<String,Any>]
                print(jsonArray)
            } else {
                print("bad json")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }, failure: {
        (operation, error) in
        self.stopAnimation()
        print(error)
        self.alert(message: error.localizedDescription)
    })
```

when I print the json string means they show to string:

```
"[{\"propertyId\":\"1\",\"inspectionTemplateId\":1118,\"value\":[{\"widgetControllerId\":141,\"value\":\"Flood Summary Name\"},{\"widgetControllerId\":142,\"value\":\"Did the property flood?\"},{\"widgetControllerId\":143,\"value\":\"no\"}]}]"
```

But when I directly gives the string means it will convert to array.

```
let jsonstring = "[{\"propertyId\":\"1\",\"inspectionTemplateId\":1118,\"value\":[{\"widgetControllerId\":141,\"value\":\"Flood Summary Name\"},{\"widgetControllerId\":142,\"value\":\"Did the property flood?\"},{\"widgetControllerId\":143,\"value\":\"no\"}]}]"
```

Comment: from where you're getting the `responseObject` ?

Comment: Why duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495999/ios-swiftjson-text-did-not-start-with-array-or-object-and-option-to-allow-frag ?
As suggested in the other question by @vadian, could your give us the value of `data`? Something like `print("data: \(data as NSData)")`? There could be hidden value for instance (invisible char)

Comment: This is not duplicate, this is differ from that. Don't make duplicate please.@Larme

Comment: from server@Mukesh

Comment: Old question I got answer.@Larme

Comment: Can you add the code ?

Comment: **What** does not work? And why do you call `jsonObject(with: data` twice?

Comment: Quick question, could you show the real input of `print("jsonstring is:, \(jsonstring!)")`? How it looks in Console. I'm wondering if you have not a JSON Stringified.

Comment: Already I added the code, I parse the Api using AFNetworking, That gives the responseObject from API.@Mukesh

Comment: When I add the Json Object that was converting to array but store the object in string means not working@vadian

Comment: I updated the full code@Larme

Comment: Why don't you take advantage of `AFNetworking` and use `manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()` instead of `manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer()`?

Comment: Ok I will take that@Larme

Comment: Not related, but `NSSet(array: ["text/plain", "text/html", "application/json"]) as Set<NSObject> as Set<NSObject>! as! Set<String>?` is horrendous. Why not simply `Set(["text/plain", "text/html", "application/json"])`? And why `NSMutableDictionary` for an **im**mutable constant?

Comment: Your solution give some good idea to me.. Thanks.

Comment: I changed now that constant, Thanks@vadian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` with `AFJSONResponseSerializer` like this:

```
var params = NSMutableDictionary()
params = [
    "inspectionLogId": inspectionLogIdStr
]
let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()
manager.requestSerializer.setValue("", forHTTPHeaderField: "apptoken")
manager.requestSerializer.setValue(strAppToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "token")
let urlString:NSString = NSString(format: "%@%@", ApiConstantFile().baseUrlProperty,ApiConstantFile().getTemplateDataUrl)
print(urlString)
manager.get(urlString as String, parameters: params, progress: nil, success: {
    (operation, responseObject) in
    self.stopAnimation()
    print(responseObject)

}, failure: {
    (operation, error) in
    self.stopAnimation()
    print(error)
    self.alert(message: error.localizedDescription)
})
```